# Passing an array item to another activity, from a spinner

Tags: android, arrays, sdk, resources, spinner

Hi guys please help me here, I have a spinner that looks like this:

On the Activity:

```
final Spinner cmbOpciones = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CmbOpciones);
spinner_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.animal , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cmbOpciones.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);
```

On the Layout:

```
<Spinner  android:prompt="@string/Poronga"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                   android:id="@+id/CmbOpciones"/>
```

With an array:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="animal">
        <item>Elephant</item>
        <item>Turtle</item>
        <item>Rabbit</item>
        <item>Mouse</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

How can I pass the selected item of the array on the spinner, to another activity, like in a textview or something like that? Is there a way to do this with strings? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cmbOpciones.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Horario.class);
                intent.putExtra("selected", cmbOpciones.getSelectedItem().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

on Receiving side

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras != null)
    {
        String selectedItem = extras.getString("selected");
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt01);
            tv.setText(selectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: where is the textview? is it in same activity or another acitivity

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this...

```
cmbOpciones.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int pos, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(<YourActivity>.this, Horario.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected", parentView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Then in the activity that you open...

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();
extras = i.getBundleExtra("extras");
String selected = "";
if(extras!=null){
    selected = extras.getStringExtra("selected");
}
```

Comment: Which are? Can't do much with that information without knowing what

Comment: Fixed one error... you need to change `ClassB` yourself. What is the class you are going to start?

Comment: Move the entire intent part to a new method like start activity. I will post code soon.

Comment: Instead of just `this` write `<activity name>.this`